# open shift does not return the depolyment configuration of a newly deployed app

Tags: openshift

hi i deployed a new app to open shift with

```
oc new-app devopswithopenshift/welcome:latest --name=myapp
```

i can see the deplpoyment details of the app ("myapp") in the console (developer) . I can see the YAML definition of the deployment as `myapp`

However when i run the command

```
C:\Docker\welcome\sh>oc get deploymentconfigs
No resources found in welcome namespace.
```

Any idea why

Answer (score 0):

Since a few versions, `oc new-app` will now create a `Deployment` by default instead of a `DeploymentConfig`, so you can get the Deployment via

```
oc get deployment
```

If you want to restore the old behaviour, you can use `oc new-app` with the `--as-deployment-config` option:

```
oc new-app devopswithopenshift/welcome:latest --name=myapp --as-deployment-config
```